# Testing the speed of gravitational waves in superfluids

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, superfluidity

Ok. Light can be slowed down in superfluids. I would like to know whether if a Cavendish like experiment could be possible within inside superfluids i.e, to rotate two balls such that to observe their gravitational attraction just like the big G is determined and test whether gravitational waves(might take debroglie wavelength) are slowed down or not?
Or whether it could be tested for celestial bodies' gravitational wavelength (or debroglie wavelength) redshifted well enough to an observable limit. Would deduce something about gravitons?

Comment: Gravitational waves haven't yet been  directly observed

Comment: Ruslan there are theories about the superfluidity of space itself. SVT and BEC vacuum theory.

Comment: Update: Gravitational waves are now directly observed and also observed as fluctuations on the CMB radiation.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question, but I'm not sure whether you would get a similar slowing of gravity waves.

Light waves are slowed because their associated electric field polarises the medium it's passing through, and the induced electric dipole interacts with the original light wave. Gravitational waves can't induce a dipole moment, but they can induce a quadrupole moment and the induced quadrupole would (in principle) reradiate gravity waves. I have never seen a calculation of whether this would slow the gravity wave. though it seems plausible.

The problem is that the interaction of gravity waves with matter is so weak that a lab experiment of the type you describe is currently far beyond anything we could actually do.

Comment: Please also shed some light on the graviton boson stuff, suppose the two Cavendish balls are made of another superfluid/supersolid or some other bosonic balls?

Comment: The slowing of light and gravity waves (if it happens) is an entirely classical effect. What "gravity boson stuff" are you referring to?

Comment: I am laymen. I mean gravitons are spin2 and the superfluids are also bosonic and photon is spin1, so their might be some interactions between them?

Comment: @WaqarAhmad: I'm not aware there is anything special about the slowing of light in e.g. superfluid helium. Light can be dramatically slowed in Bose-Einstein condensates, which are I suppose a type of superfluid, but this is due to the resonant interation between the light and electrons in the atoms. This woukldn't happen for gravity waves.